# Unsupported relations for schema

Tags: go, go-gorm

I have four nested models (simplified here):

```
type Client struct {
    gorm.Model
    UUID                   uuid.UUID `gorm:"type:uuid"`
    Activity               Activity 
}

type Activity struct {
    gorm.Model
    ClientID        uint
    LoginActivities []LoginActivity
}

type LoginActivity struct {
    gorm.Model
    ActivityID uint
    UUID       uuid.UUID
    Timestamp  time.Time
    Device     DeviceInfo
}

type DeviceInfo struct {
    gorm.Model
    LoginActivityID uint
    Platform        string
}
```

And I want to retrieve all nested models with:

```
database.db.
    Where("uuid = ?", clientID).
    Preload("Activity.LoginActivities.DeviceInfos").
    First(&client). 
    Error
```

However, I get the error `DeviceInfos: unsupported relations for schema LoginActivity`

Is the model wrongly set or the query wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've used `Preload("Activity.LoginActivities.DeviceInfos")` but the member that represents the relationship in `LoginActivity` is `Device`.

You should instead preload with `Preload("Activity.LoginActivities.Device")`

Comment: You are right and now the error is gone (and the right select statement is generated). However, the object returned is filled only up to `LoginActivities`, but the `Device` field stays empty. Any clue?

Comment: Nevermind, it was an additional mapping error I just found in the representation models... Thanks!

Comment: This issue does seem to be related to a possible misuse of `Preload()`. In my case, I was using `Preload()` with `Raw()`, which I don't really need because I already retrieved the fields I need of the related table on the `Raw()` query.  Removing the `Preload()` fixed the issue